# Service 'app' failed to build: COPY failed Laravel with Docker

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

[image]I'm setting up Docker for my laravel project following the blog post by [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose)

When I run the command  `docker-compose up -d`from Step 8 from the blog post
I get the following error:

> ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder700663646/composer.lock: no such file or directory

Below is the configs from ~/larave.-app/Dockerfile

```html
FROM php:7.2-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    mysql-client \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Can anyone help me to get through this issue ?

Comment: Are you sure the `composer.lock` file exists in the directory from which you run your command?

Comment: Make sure `composer,lock` file exists and if its not present you create it by running `composer install`

Comment: @PierreB. There is `composer.json` file in the project directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker build is trying to copy non-existent file `composer.lock` and fail. You forgot to run the step which would generate the `composer.lock` file:

> Next, use Dockers' composer image to mount the directories that you
> will need for your Laravel project and avoid the overhead of
> installing Composer globally:
>
> ```
> docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app composer install
> ```

It's not clearly indicated in the tutorial but this will generate a `composer.lock` in your directory and allow the copy command to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Just been following the same instructions (on Digital Ocean) and had to do them all over again due to one little mistake - thought I would share:

My mistake way that I missed the colon (:) in Step 1 of their instructions -

This part:

**docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app composer install**

After I replaced the $(pwd) part with my directory (by typing pwd and copying any pasting my directory instead of the $(pwd)- make sure not to delete the :/app which follows after

after I did this step properly all the rest went well. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and solved!
my .yml file is not in same directory with Dockerfile because of this I add Dockerfile directory in Dockerfile.

myDockerfileDir/compose.json
myDockerfileDir/compose.lock